# Colored grid congruences

Tags: color, grid-layouts

How can I construct a colored grid in Mathematica representing the remainder of $x^{y}$ modulo a given prime $p$?(with coordinates) 
As such:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
p = 7;
remainders = Table[Mod[x^y, p], {x, 1, 6}, {y, 1, 6}];
MatrixPlot[remainders]
```

You can look at the documentation on `ArrayPlot` to get an idea of how you can format the colours and grid lines to match whatever you have in mind.

Comment: One can also use `Outer` instead of `Table` and apply `Mod` in a vectorized way: `remainders = Mod[Outer[Power, Range[p - 1], Range[p - 1]], p]`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

```
p = 11;
remainders = Mod[Outer[Power, Range[p - 1], Range[p - 1]], p];
color = Most[
  Hue[#] & /@ 
   Subdivide[p - 1]]; (*or use color=ColorData["Rainbow"]/@Subdivide[p-2]*)
Legended[ArrayPlot[remainders, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, 20], Style["y", Black, 20]}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
  PlotLabel -> Framed@Style["p=" <> ToString[p], Black, 20, Bold], 
  ColorRules -> Thread[Range[p - 1] -> color], Mesh -> All], 
 SwatchLegend[color, Range[p - 1], LegendMarkerSize -> 20]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Let's use Henrik's solution:

```
p = 7;
remainders = Mod[Outer[Power, Range[p - 1], Range[p - 1]], p];

color = {Red, Green, Brown, Purple, Darker[Green, 0.8], Yellow};
Legended[ArrayPlot[remainders, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["a", Black, 20], Style["k", Black, 20]}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
  PlotLabel -> Framed@Style["p=7", Black, 20, Bold], 
  ColorRules -> Thread[Range@6 -> color], Mesh -> All], 
 SwatchLegend[color, Range@6, LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 30}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how do I make it work for a generic given prime $p$?

Comment: @James See edit..